# Wait for and then receive textfield input without freezing GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, freeze

I hope I'm not duplicating a question, but I couldn't find one specifically for my issue.
I'm developing a small math flash card application, using JavaFX to create the GUI. The program should runs as follow:

1. user selects settings, then presses *start* button.
2. gui displays question and textfield for user input.
3. user inputs answer within X amount of seconds or gui automatically move onto the next question - alternatively, user can move onto next question immediately by pressing *next* button.
4. GUI displays score and average.

The problems is `getText()` from user textfield is processed as soon as *start* button is pressed, without giving the user a chance to enter an answer. How do I make the program wait for X amount of seconds or for the *next* button to be clicked before processing the user's answer? Here's my code:

```java
//start button changes view and then runs startTest()
start.setOnAction(e -> {

        setLeft(null);
        setRight(null);

        setCenter(test_container);
        running_program_title.setText(getDifficulty().name() + " Test");
        buttons_container.getChildren().clear();
        buttons_container.getChildren().addAll(next, quit, submit);

        startTest();
    });
```

Here is the problem code... at least how I see it.

```java
//startTest method calls askAdd() to ask an addition question
void startTest() {

    int asked = 0;
    int correct = 0;

    while (asked < numberOfQuestions) {
        if(askAdd()){
        correct++;
        asked++;
    }
}

boolean askAdd() {

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * getMultiplier());
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * getMultiplier());

     //ask question
     question.setText("What is " + a + " + " + b + "?");

     //code needed to pause method and wait for user input for X seconds

     //retrieve user answer and return if its correct
     return answer.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(a+b));
}
```

I've tried using `Thread.sleep(X)` but that freezes the gui for however long I specify and then goes through the `addAsk()` method and the loop before going to the test screen. (I know because I had the program set up to print the questions and answer input to the console). It shows the last question and that's all.

I didn't include the *next* button code because I can't get the gui to go to the test page anyway.

Any help on any of the code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by various methods.

[PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) is one of the many apt solution present. It waits for `X time interval` and then performs a `Task`. It can `start`, `restart`, `stop at any moment`.

Here is an example of how it can used to achieve a similar result.

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main extends Application {

    int questionIndex = 0;
    int noOfQuestions = 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox box = new VBox(10);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(box), 500, 200);
        ObservableList<String> questions =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList("1) Whats your (full) name?",
                                                  "2) How old are you?",
                                                  "3) Whats your Birthday?",
                                                  "4) What starsign does that make it?",
                                                  "5) Whats your favourite colour?",
                                                  "6) Whats your lucky number?",
                                                  "7) Do you have any pets?",
                                                  "8) Where are you from?",
                                                  "9) How tall are you?",
                                                  "10) What shoe size are you?");

        ObservableList<String> answers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        final PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(5000));

        Label questionLabel = new Label(questions.get(questionIndex));
        Label timerLabel = new Label("Time Remaining : ");
        Label time = new Label();
        time.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: RED");
        TextField answerField = new TextField();

        Button nextQuestion = new Button("Next");

        pt.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
                time.setText(String.valueOf(5 - (int)newValue.toSeconds()));
            }
        });

        box.getChildren().addAll(questionLabel, answerField, new HBox(timerLabel, time), nextQuestion);

        nextQuestion.setOnAction( (ActionEvent event) -> {
            answers.add(questionIndex, answerField.getText());

            //Check if it is the last question
            if(questionIndex == noOfQuestions-1) {
                pt.stop();
                box.getChildren().clear();
                IntStream.range(0, noOfQuestions).forEach(i -> {
                    Label question = new Label("Question : " + questions.get(i));
                    question.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: RED");
                    Label answer = new Label("Answer : " + answers.get(i));
                    answer.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: GREEN");
                    box.getChildren().addAll(question, answer);
                });
            }
            // All other time
            else {
                //Set new question
                questionLabel.setText(questions.get(++questionIndex));
                answerField.clear();
                pt.playFromStart();
            }
        });

        pt.setOnFinished( ( ActionEvent event ) -> {
            nextQuestion.fire();
        });
        pt.play();

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the timer you should (IMO) use a `Timeline`. Here is an example:

```
public class MultiGame extends Application {
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    final int allowedTime = 5; //seconds
    final DoubleProperty percentOfTimeUsed = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    final Timeline timer =
            new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(percentOfTimeUsed, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(allowedTime), new KeyValue(percentOfTimeUsed, 1))
            );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.progressProperty().bindBidirectional(percentOfTimeUsed);
        root.setTop(progressBar);

        Button answer = new Button("Answer");
        answer.setOnAction(ae -> restart());// the on answer handler

        Button skip = new Button("Skip");
        skip.setOnAction(ae -> restart());// the skip question handler

        HBox mainContent = new HBox(15,
                new Label("Your Question"), new TextField("The answer"),  answer, skip);
        root.setCenter(mainContent);

        timer.setOnFinished(ae -> restart());// the end of timer handler

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        restart();
    }

    void restart() { timer.stop(); timer.playFromStart(); }

    void pause() { timer.pause(); }

    void resume() { timer.play(); }
}
```

You just need to capture the text from the input in between the starting of the timeline and the `restart` method.

Comment: You have a couple of misunderstandings in your answer.  You probably want to set the allowedTime to five seconds rather than 500 seconds.  The [`progressProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#progressProperty--) should be a number between zero and one, so you should not bidirectionally bind it to a value which varies from zero to one hundred. A unidirectional bind is preferred here: `progressBar.progressProperty().bind(percentOfTimeUsed.divide(100.0));`

Comment: @jewelsea That explains the problem with allowed time - Thank you for pointing that out. Upated example.